# How to format a long <pre> HTML block suitable for width limited device such as iPhone

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, html, css

I have a long **pre** block, I want it to be view in mobile browsers, such as iPhone

e.g.

```
a very long pre block start here here here here here here here here here here
    2nd line with intent
        3rd line with intent
```

How to make make the wordwrap, but keep the indentations?

```
e.g.
    a very long pre block start here here here here here here 
    here here here here
        2nd line with intent
            3rd line with intent
```

I don't want to have scrollbar for mobile device, so better to have some way to auto word-wrap the sentence.

The most similar method I have tried is to use CSS

```
 pre {
            white-space: pre-line;
        }
```

But not exactly as I want as demonstrated above.

**Updated: Link:** http://pastehtml.com/view/bisxytioa.html

Comment: try this:pre{white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word}

Comment: now, are the 2nd and 3rd lines part of the text above it? or do you want new lines created with further indentations?

Comment: @LotusH, Yes, quite similar, see: http://pastehtml.com/view/bisykurru.html, except the new line does not align with the same as the 1st line

Comment: @Howard what do you mean by 'does not align with the same as the 1st line'? Do you want them start at the same position and don't want the indents? If so, only 'word-wrap:break-word' will do.

Comment: @LotusH, when you resize this page in your browser: http://pastehtml.com/view/bisykurru.html, when width get smaller, the string will wrapped into 2nd line, but it is not following the same intentation of the 1st line.

Comment: @LotusH, I have made a better example: http://pastehtml.com/view/biupkorna.html. What I want is: if there is a line-wrap, the new line should never exceed the left margin of the line immediate above.

Comment: I'm more interested in the "why?". Is it for code, or for what? If it is a fixed indentation, then why not mark it up differently. Is it really a pre?

Comment: @Howard Could you update the question to include that `white-space:pre-wrap` is not useful in this scenario due to no-indent for originally indented lines. A lot of answers are stating to use this... I agree with @Matthew Rudy though, `pre` might not be the correct scenario here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with Javascript. This goes through the `<pre>` and wraps each section in a `<div>` with `padding-left` equal to the number of spaces of indentation. In the demo I made the size of the `<pre>` the size of an iPhone screen to demonstrate the wrapping.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Script:

```js
var pre = document.getElementById( 'pre' ),
    sections = pre.textContent.trim().split( '\n' ),
    paddingPerChar = 9;

for( var index=0, html='', padding=0; index < sections.length; index++ ) {
    padding = ( sections[index].length - sections[index].trim().length ) *  paddingPerChar;
    html += '<div style="padding-left:' + padding + 'px;">' + sections[index].trim() + '</div>';
};

pre.innerHTML = html;
```

#### HTML:

```html
<pre id="pre">
1. a very long pre block start here here here here here here here here here here
    A. 2nd line with indent long pre block start here here here here here here here here here
        a. 3rd line with indent
    B. 4th line th indent long pre block start here here here here here here here her
    C. 5th line
2. 6th Line
</pre>
```

#### CSS:

```css
pre {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 460px;
    width: 320px;    
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

#### Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not the most ideal solution, and probably not the solution you were looking for, but it's a solution none the less that does the job. It uses jQuery to replace the pre block with a list, as lists preserve indents on text wrapping.

http://pastehtml.com/view/bj4d0az5r.html

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use PHP (or anything like that). For example:

Detect what browser / platform has been used:

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
```

And for mobile OS's you could use an if/else statement with a wordwrap function to break and display your content. For example:

```
<?php
$text = "A very long woooooooooooord.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 8, "\n", true);

echo "$newtext\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works in every mobile browser I have tried them all on iOS & Android if you want screen shots let me know. All that is needed is one css tag

```
pre {
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

PRE will fill its container automatically. As long as your container is sized to the width of the screen and has no overflow this works perfectly (preserves indents across word-wrapped line-breaks).

Answer (score 1):

Wordwrap the content of the pre so that you do not exceed the fixed with.

```
pre {
 width:100%;
 word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

this may fix your problem.

you could also change width to a fixed with no wider than the iphone browser. The key is to wrap the text though so that it does not force the width of the housing element to be larger than the screen.

Answer (score -2):

I’m afraid there’s no way to do it CSS, because CSS has no “knowledge” of things like the actual textual content of an element, like the leading spaces. So some different approach is needed. If you have control over the markup, you could replace the `pre` element by a `div` element containing single-line `div` elements with `class` attributes corresponding to the desired indentation levels. Then you just specify suitable left margins. Demo:

http://pastehtml.com/view/bjbgnb1v3.html

(The demo sets the left margin in `ch` units but uses a setting in `em` units as a reasonable backup. For a monospace font, one `em` is close to the width of two characters.)

This doesn’t handle all the features of `pre` so if multiple whitespace inside a line needs to be preserved, add `white-space: pre-wrap`.

An even more logical approach would be to use `div` elements nested so that the depth of nesting corresponds to the level of indentation. This would make the stylesheet simple but the markup would look awkward.

If you cannot control the HTML markup, you may need to do things client-side (convert the `pre` element to other elements), similarly to the code in AncientMan’s suggestion.